# Multiple infoBubbles in google maps api shows just last added

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobubble

I have problem with infoBubble in google maps api v3. I load markers from db and add infoBubbles for that markers. But work just infoBubble from last added marker. Can u see the problem please?

```
 var gmarkers = [];
 var map;

 function load() {

     var defaultLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(49.8248188, 15.4684482);

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
         center: defaultLocation,
         zoom: 8,
         mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
     });

     downloadUrl("generatexml.php", function (data) {
         var xml = data.responseXML;
         var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
             var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
             var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
             var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map,
                 position: point
             });

             var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                 content: '<div' + name + '</div',
                 boxClass: 'info-box',
                 alignBottom: true,
                 pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-150, -40),
                 maxWidth: 300,
                 disableAutoPan: false,
                 hideCloseButton: false,
             });

             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                 infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                 console.log(infoBubble.content);
             });

             gmarkers.push(marker);

         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: This looks like a closure problem - checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7054057/1370442

Comment: Many identical questions on this site. Please search. Further to that, you should be looking at creating a single `infoWindow` object and setting its content dynamically. Just a hint.

Comment: Oh thx I used infoBubble so I didn't care about infoWindow. Thank you

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that. The same applies with `infoBubble`. It must have a `setContent` method if I remember well. This applies, of course, if you don't need multiple bubbles opened at the same time.

Comment: Possibly relevant question [Close open InfoBubble when open a new (gMap v3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910227/close-open-infobubble-when-open-a-new-gmap-v3/11911206#11911206)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, just replace:

> google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
>
> ```
>             infoBubble.open(map, marker);
>             console.log(infoBubble.content);
>
>         });
> ```

with:

> google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
>
> ```
>                    infoBubble.setContent(this.content);
>                    infoBubble.open(map, this);
>
>          });
> ```

Thank you for help.